# Assign user_str with a string from user input, with the prompt: 'Enter a string:\n' user_str = int(input('Enter a string:\n') print(user_str)

Tags: python-3.x

Having problems assigning user_str with a string from user input, with the prompt: 'Enter a string:\n'

```
user_str = int(input('Enter a string:\n')

print(user_str)
```

Comment: Try `user_str = raw_input('Enter a string:\n')`.

Comment: Please state your problem clearly, including any error messages. You need to show what you have tried already, as well as evidence of some sort of research effort on your part.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Your prompt says enter a string, but you are trying to convert it to an integer. Which do you want? And what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert it to a string

```
user_str = input('Enter a string:\n')
print(user_str)
```